# packaging a python application

Tags: python, packaging

How can I pack and distribute a python application consisting of multiple files? My application requires a configuration file which has to filled in by the user.

I guess I am looking for steps similar to configure/make/make install/make documentation that I use on my Linux machine.

Comment: You can read up on packaging your projects on the official [Python site](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html#distutils-index).

Comment: Please read [The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Packaging](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Also take a look at [5 tips for packaging your Python projects](http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/5-tips-for-packaging-your-python-projects/).

Comment: As an aside, you can always have your program *output* a configuration template for the user to complete, rather than shipping it as a separate file in the package.

Answer (score 2):

There are different solutions available, each involves your codebase adhering to a certain file-folder hierarchy, and declaring any dependencies used.

There is no right or wrong answer from the options available, but as a professional Python programmer who leads a team of Python programmers - and we've tried all of them - I recommend [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) as a comprehensive and modern solution.

Their site documentation explains it all.

Comment: This is more or less a link-only answer and/or an answer recommending a certain tool. Hatchling (the new kid on the block, from the PyPA team), could be better than Poetry.

Comment: It would be a waste of time to provide a hardcoded answer relating to a specific tool whose methods might change in time. I've also stated in my answer there is no "right or wrong", yet you've voted me down and given a different recommendation.

The question cannot be explicitly answered until a particular solution is chosen, beyond linking the other solutions too or providing working setups for all of them I'm not sure what better answer you're hoping for.

Comment: Recommendation questions/answers are explicitly out-of-scope on SO. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: Also: the packaging.python.org guide has up-to-date recommendations. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: I'm more interested in helping OP than being au fait with rule specifics. The issue you've raised relates to the question asked more than my answer. Why don't you submit an answer yourself if you feel you have something better to offer that is rule-aligned.

Comment: Furthermore: there are three other answers to this question that link to various projects/guides for packaging that have since been deleted and turned into comments.