# Packaging a Python library with an executable

Tags: python, packaging, setup.py

I just finished a module and want to package it. I've read the documentation and this question [packaging a python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156333/packaging-a-python-application) but I am not sure about how to proceed when I don't have a package to import but a script to launch instead.

The project looks like that:

```
Project/
|-- README
|-- requirement.txt
|-- driver.py
|-- run.py
|-- module_1
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- class_1.py
|   |-- class_2.py
|-- module 2
|-- |-- __init__.py
|-- |-- class_1.py
|-- |-- class_2.py
```

In order to launch the tool I do:

```
python run.py arg1 --option arg2
```

`driver.py` imports all other modules and defines a `Driver` class and some functions. `run.py` imports `driver.py`, parse arguments, setups the logger and calls the function one after the others to do the job.

I'm not sure about the configuration of `setup.py`, also do I need a global `__init__.py` at the root? From what I've understand, I will only be able to do `import Project` not to launch the script `run.py` with its arguments.

From other readings, maybe I should try to tell that `Driver.py` is the package and use the `entry_points` option of `setup()`. But I don't understand how to do all of it properly.

Thank you for your kind help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Generally, you only distribute python packages as modules when the entire project fits in a single module file.  If your project is more complex than that, it's usually best to structure your project as a package with an `__init__.py` file.  Here is what your project would look like converted to a package

```
Project/
|-- README
|-- requirement.txt
|-- setup.py
|-- scripts/
|   |-- driver.py
|-- driver/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- module_1
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- class_1.py
|   |   |-- class_2.py
|   |-- module_2
|   |-- |-- __init__.py
|   |-- |-- class_1.py
|   |-- |-- class_2.py
```

I renamed your `run.py` to `scripts/driver.py` and the code you previously had in `driver.py` is now `driver/__init__.py`.

Your `setup.py` should look like this

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='driver',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    scripts=['scripts/driver.py'],
)
```

This will copy `scripts/driver.py` to the python Scripts directory.  I renamed `run.py` to `driver.py` since `run` is pretty generic and you want your script names to be unique since all python packages share the same scripts location.

Alternatively, you could use the `console_scripts` entry point.  In this case, you wouldn't have a separate `scripts/driver.py` script.  Instead, you would just have a function inside your package.  In this case, you could move all the code from `scripts/driver.py` into `driver/command_line.py` and put it inside a function called `main()`.  Then change your `setup.py` to this

```
setup(
    name='driver',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['driver=driver.command_line:main'],
    }
)
```

Also, you should read [this docs page on python packaging](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).  It covers the basics and a lot of the common use cases.

Comment: Thank you @Abel, this is now clear to me! Will try this at work Monday! Is there any advantage to use one solution over the other one? First one seems clearer I guess.

Comment: In this structure, how does one import something from, say, module1 in driver.py?

Comment: (without having to actually install the project)

Comment: @Alex There is no driver.py anymore. `driver` is now a package. If you wanted to import something from module_1, you would use `import driver.module_1`. But you would still need to install the project or add it to the pythonpath