# How to make a package which includes an executable built from C++?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-packaging

I am trying to build a python package from a program I am writing. At some point of this program I have an instance like this

```
p = subprocess.check_call(path_exe, cwd=directory_out, shell=True,
                          stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

In my code `path_exe` (the address of the executable) is given manually. I would like to be able to do a package to install the whole package so that the executable is copied somewhere in the python environment and so that I can have access to its address.

I hope I am sufficiently clear...

Comment: You could determine the _path_ (not the "address") to the executable in your package's `__init__.py` file and define `path_exe` in it. A convenient way to do that would be to put the executable in the same directory as as the `__init__.py` file and use the system `__file__` variable automatically provided to Python scripts/modules when they run to specify its location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Packaging a Python library with an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405248/packaging-a-python-library-with-an-executable)

Comment: I don't think it is the same. There is no executable file to be included inside the python package in their question